# Multiplying brackets

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Why this:
$(3 \ast (3^{k-1} + 1) - 2)$
equals to:
$(3 \ast 3^{k-1} + 3 - 2)$
and why/how from this we get to this:
$(3^k + 1)$

Comment: Just evaluate from left to right, giving precedence to parentheses, exponents, multiplication, division, addition, subtraction (in that order, respectively). See solomoan's answer for more specifics to your particular question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $a*(b+c)=a*b+a*c$ and $x^m*x^n=x^{m+n}$